# Twitter Integration in android without browser view

Tags: android, twitter

I am developing an application that needs twittter integration. I want to perform login as user clicks twitter button from app, view tweets and also able to post tweets. No other features are needed. I want to show this in app itself and not in browser. Can anyone help me with exact source for this. I tried many codes from github and all, but am not getting. Please help.

Comment: Please be more specific then (paraphrasing) "write this twitter app for me pl0x". What specific problem did you encounter with the twitter client you found on Github?

Comment: please elaborate more,while asking any question be specific

Answer (score 1):

Please view something called as the twitter API's which will help you with this .

https://dev.twitter.com/

For developing Facebook applications you can use the Graph API for facebook

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 1):

Twitter4j is the way to go.

[To start use this tutorial](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-post-twitter-status-from-android/).

---

The complete list of examples to do each twitter stuff will be [found here](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/tree/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples)

Comment: but it is saying cannot connect to twitter...what is wrong in the above mentioned code ? whenever i check the t button, it says "twitter connection failed"

Comment: I'll need the logcat output for this.

Answer (score 0):

1) Integration without Browser view

Methods to directly **Login to Twitter using Username and Password are Depreciated**,
So one must Authenticate through Calling the Url `http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize`
and in callback you will get `Token and Secret Key`,which you can use further.

2) To View Tweets and Able to Post Tweets.

You can use [Twitter REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api) or you can also use some already build Twitter Api like i have used  - [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html)
You can also find code example using Twitter4J here [Code Example](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html)

You will just need to Download the `twitter4j jar` file and add it to Your project Build Path and Add JAR File.